# How to set the width of a control 50% of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

This is a simple thing but is driving me crazy. I need 2 controls to fill 50% percent of the screen width each one (they are side by side) but I'm unable to detect how to do so.

I tried hundred of autolayout combination without success. Please advice.

Comment: Autolayout is great for simple things, but it rapidly becomes more trouble than it's worth. I'd recommend just turning it off, and using `CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;` to set the controls' widths in the code.

Comment: @Nerrolken: I'll check if setting the width programatically helps better. Thanks

Comment: Show what views you have, what constraints you're currently using and what the result is. Are you setting the views to have equal widths?

Comment: @Nain: I'm not setting the views to have equal widths. I currently have no constraints so I'm willing to test any suggestion.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or a xib?  Or are you creating your views in code?

Comment: @robmayoff: I'm using storyboard

Comment: that is why I don't like auto-layout... without auto-layout, its so simple...

Answer (score 0):

The following code with auto layout will always make sure your boxes are taking exactly 50% of their parent view in width.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

    NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view1][view2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view1(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view2(200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

}
```

The trick with it is to set the left attribute of the 2nd view (control) to the centerX of the parent view and the right attribute of the 1st view (control) to the parent view centerX also

Comment: In storyboard the same thing can be accomplished by selecting both elements (Command+click) and going to Editor > Pin > Widths Equally. Then pin the other dimensions of your elements as necessary.